# Refused to load the image 'blob:...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: html, mapbox, content-security-policy

I got this error:

```
Refused to load the image 'blob:file:///cf368042-bf23-42b6-b07c-54189d3b0e01' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

While trying to load a mapboxGL map.
This is my CSP tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="
      worker-src blob:; 
      child-src blob: gap:;
      default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

Comment: Add 'img-src blob:' to the Content-Security-Policy value. Or else add 'blob:' to the existing 'default-src' value.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is the fix for both image and base64.

Need to add `img-src 'self' blob: data:;` As follow:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="
      worker-src blob:; 
      child-src blob: gap:;
      img-src 'self' blob: data:;
      default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

Comment: What is the use of `data:` here? `img-src 'self' blob:` can be added instead right?

Comment: yes, according to the spec, "data:" is a different schema than "blob:".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs

Comment: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *may* not be preferable because of security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `img-src blob:` in your CSP value.
Since `img-src` is absent, it is using `default-src`.
You can set `img-src *` also.
Please take a look at https://content-security-policy.com/ to check how to add CSP for image.

Comment: From the link: `*` "allows any URL except data: blob: filesystem: schemes." That's why it wasn't working in this case, since the fallback `default-src *` does not include blob.

Answer (score 2):

### For Ghost + Nginx

I faced the same issue while setting up a ghost blog proxied via Nginx.
To solve this I had to update the server block in nginx with the below headers:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "img-src 'self' blob: data:; default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
```

This fix should generally apply to apps serving images via Nginx and not just limited to Ghost CMS.

**A starter CSP header for Nginx + Ghost would look like this:**

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://www.googletagmanager.com https://code.jquery.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; img-src 'self' data: blob: https://static.ghost.org https://supapjpiqdfzuaordcdx.supabase.co https://www.gravatar.com https://images.unsplash.com; connect-src 'self' https://ghost.org https://www.google-analytics.com https://resources.ghost.io https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; object-src 'none'; media-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self';" always;
```

Add more to this as required by allowing the URLs that are needed and not using wildcard *

Comment: Worked for me. I spent hours trying out diffrent meta tags config in my index. But I guess since I was using nginx I had to change it in it configuration. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add in content security policy

```
img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  blob: data:  'unsafe-eval';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, set `img-src` policy will fix the problem, but if you still get the same error.
Note that if you use the "helmet" middleware at the same time, your problem may come from it, and you need to configure it separately.

Comment: how to do in in Tomcat?