# Content Security Policy error when embeding PDF in Angular html

Tags: angular, pdf, embed, content-security-policy

In my angular application, I am trying to display a pdf in the HTML. I am using  as below,

```
<embed [src]="pdfContent" width="100%" height="1930px" type="application/pdf" />
```

It works fine when I run the app on `localhost:4200`, but when I deploy the changes to my application server(weblogic), it gives me an error 'Content Security Policy' shown below:

> Refused to load plugin data from 'blob because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
> 'unsafe-eval'

I tried to fix using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484216/refused-to-load-the-image-blob-because-it-violates-the-following-content-s) : but doesn't work. Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: This one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31211359/5468463

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to fix using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484216/refused-to-load-the-image-blob-because-it-violates-the-following-content-s): but doesn't work.

It's important how you do use above fix. If you just insert a meta tag with Content Security Policy (CSP) - it does not work because you just add a second CSP. but the first one (published via HTTP header) continue block.

AFAIK the WebLogic Server publishes Content Security Policy via HTTP response header by default. You have to edit `httpd.conf` file and add `blob:` to the related directive: `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' blob:` in your case.